# How to remove an item in an array in if else statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms

To do:

- select 0 hr only show 15, 30, 45 minutes select
- 1,2,3,4 hr show 0,15, 30, 45 minutes

I want to shorthen this if else statement

```
onHourChange(hours: number) {

if (hours === 0) {
 this.minuteOptions = [
  { value: 15, display: '15' },
  { value: 30, display: '30' },
  { value: 45, display: '45' },
 ]


} else if (hours === 1) {
  this.minuteOptions = [
    { value: 0, display: '00' },
    { value: 15, display: '15' },
    { value: 30, display: '30' },
    { value: 45, display: '45' },
  ];

}
```

Use this array to delete or remove from the array when the value 0 is selected

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hourOptions = [
      { value: 0, display: '0' },
      { value: 1, display: '1' },
      { value: 2, display: '2' },
      { value: 3, display: '3' },
      { value: 4, display: '4' },
    ];
    this.minuteOptions = [
      { value: 0, display: '00' },
      { value: 15, display: '15' },
      { value: 30, display: '30' },
      { value: 45, display: '45' },
    ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: I still can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options how you can delete an element from the array.

Look at the snippet below, there you can find examples with `filter`, `slice` and `splice` array methods for removing items.

```js
class TimeFilter {
  onHourChange(hours) {
    const noZeroMinutes = item => !(hours === 0 && item.value === 0);
    
    this.minuteOptions = [
      { value: 0, display: '0' },
      { value: 15, display: '15' },
      { value: 30, display: '30' },
      { value: 45, display: '45' },
    ].filter(noZeroMinutes); // filter the elements that have 0 minute and 0 hours
  }
}

class TimeSlice {
  onHourChange(hours) {
    this.minuteOptions = [
      { value: 0, display: '0' },
      { value: 15, display: '15' },
      { value: 30, display: '30' },
      { value: 45, display: '45' },
    ];
    
    if (hours === 0) {
      this.minuteOptions = this.minuteOptions.slice(1); // remove first element from the array
    }
  }
}

class TimeSplice {
  onHourChange(hours) {
    this.minuteOptions = [
      { value: 0, display: '0' },
      { value: 15, display: '15' },
      { value: 30, display: '30' },
      { value: 45, display: '45' },
    ];
    
    if (hours === 0) {
      this.minuteOptions.splice(0, 1); // remove first element from the array
    }
  }
}

const time = new TimeFilter();
// const time = new TimeSlice();
// const time = new TimeSplice();

time.onHourChange(0);
console.log(time.minuteOptions);
time.onHourChange(5);
console.log(time.minuteOptions);
```